# Getting Totals from select menu selections into another table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a simple HTML table that allows users to make a selection from a select menu and then enter a QTY in the next column.

I need to be able to automatically calculate the totals of the QTY column for each selection - the number of rows isn't fixed but will always be at least 1 row. I've created a simplified version of my table here:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5xtL/

Here the user can only select from 3 different fruits (Apple, Banana, Mango) and then enter a QTY for each. Once a user makes a fruit selection and/or enters the QTY I would like to automatically calculate the total for each fruit. In my example the totals would be:

Total Apples: 20
Total Bananas: 30
Total Mangoes: 5

I'm happy to use jQuery if this helps - I've been searching and can't find an example of a similar solution that counts the number of selections in each row from a select menu then calculates the total of another column in that row.

Appreciate if anyone can enlighten me as to how to achieve this or if you can point to any examples that do something similar. I'm new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/T5xtL/12/

```
$('#fruits')
    .on('change', 'select', calc)
    .on('keyup', 'input', calc);

$(document).ready(calc);

function calc(){
    var total = {};
    $('#fruits tr:has(.fruit)').each(function(){

       var $t = $(this), 

           // val : Apple | Banana | Mango
           val = $t.find('.fruit select').val(),
           qty = $t.find('input').val();

        // the qty
        qty = Number(qty);
        qty = isNaN(qty)?0:qty;

        if(!total.hasOwnProperty(val)) total[val] = 0;
        total[val] += qty;
    });

    // you would be updating the actual html here.    
    for(val in total){
        if(total.hasOwnProperty(val)){
    // NOTE that I change your 'sumApples' to 'sumApple' which follows convention of 'sum' + { the name of the fruit }
            $('#sum' + val).html(total[val]);
        }                
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks Liangliang - that works well in my quick tests. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have added an example for sum of apples. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/4Atrv/).

```
$('.qty').change(function(){
    sumApples();
});
$('.fruit').change(function(){
    sumApples();
});

function sumApples(){
    var totalApples = 0;
    $('#fruits').find('select').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'Apple'){
            var q = $(this).parent('td.fruit').next('td').find('.qty').val();
            totalApples += parseInt(q);
        }
    });
    $('#sumApples').html(totalApples);
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
$().ready(function(){

   var fruit=[];

 $('table select').each(function(){
    if(!fruit[$(this).find('option:selected').text()])      
        fruit[$(this).find('option:selected').text()]=0; 
        fruit[$(this).find('option:selected').text()]+=parseInt($(this).parent().next().find('.qty').val());

});

 $('#sumApples').text(fruit['Apple']);
 $('#sumBananas').text(fruit['Banana']);
 $('#sumMangoes').text(fruit['Mango']);

});​
```

this is example and check this link also 
http://jsfiddle.net/T5xtL/7/

Answer (score 1):

I'll just show you a sample for the bananas, I trust you'll know how to generalize this for your other products.

```
// Filter only returns the values where the inner function returns true
var bananas = $( '.fruits' ).filter( function() {

    // this selector returns the selected options
    if ( $( ':selected', this ).val() === 'Banana' ) {
         return true;
    }
}

// Now, for each banana, get its quantity, and add to the total
bananas.each( function() {
    // Get the quantity
    var qty = $( this ).next().find( 'input' ).val();

    // Add it to the bananas quantity
    // parseInt transforms a text to an integer
    var qty = qty + parseInt( $( '#sumBananas' ).text(), 10 );

    // And set the quantity in the "sumBananas" span
    $( '#sumBananas' ).text( qty );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) on KnockoutJS. Knockout is better suited to working with Models than JQuery. (They compliment each other).